# Richfaces in netbeans with maven

Tags: java, maven, netbeans, richfaces

I am trying to implement Richfaces with javax.faces-war-archetype version 2.2 in Netbeans 8.0.1 and GlassFish 4.1.

I have an existing project with richfaces implemented, if I build this it all works fine.

However when I create a new project (The exact same type and version) it gives the following error:

```
type Exception report
messageInternal Server Error
descriptionThe server encountered an internal error that prevented it from fulfilling this request.
exception java.lang.IllegalStateException
```

Even when I literally copy the pom.xml and web.xml from the working project to the new project it still gives this error.

The web.xml:

```
<?xml version='1.0' encoding='UTF-8'?>

<web-app version="3.0"
     xmlns="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee"
     xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
     xsi:schemaLocation="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee/web-app_3_0.xsd">

<display-name>Test</display-name>

<context-param>
    <description>
        Tell the runtime where we are in the project development
        lifecycle.  Valid values are: 
        Development, UnitTest, SystemTest, or Production.
        The runtime will display helpful hints to correct common mistakes
        when the value is Development.
    </description>
    <param-name>javax.faces.PROJECT_STAGE</param-name>
    <param-value>Development</param-value>
</context-param>
```

The pom.xml:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
<modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>

<groupId>nl.Test</groupId>
<artifactId>Test</artifactId>
<version>1.0-SNAPSHOT</version>
<packaging>war</packaging>
<name>${project.artifactId}</name>
<description>A simple project with war packaging that depends on JSF 2.2 and 
    javaee 6, in that order.</description>
<url>http://jsf-spec.java.net/</url>
<build>
    <finalName>${project.artifactId}</finalName>
    <plugins>
        <plugin>
            <artifactId>maven-compiler-plugin</artifactId>
            <configuration>
                <source>1.8</source>
                <target>1.8</target>
                <encoding>${project.build.sourceEncoding}</encoding>
            </configuration>
            <version>3.1</version>
        </plugin>
        <plugin>
            <artifactId>maven-war-plugin</artifactId>
            <configuration>
              <failOnMissingWebXml>false</failOnMissingWebXml>
            </configuration>
            <version>2.4</version>
        </plugin>
        <plugin>
            <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
            <artifactId>maven-resources-plugin</artifactId>
            <version>2.4.3</version>
            <configuration>
                <encoding>${project.build.sourceEncoding}</encoding>
            </configuration>
        </plugin>
    </plugins>
</build>
<properties>
  <spec.snapshot.version>2.2</spec.snapshot.version>
    <project.build.sourceEncoding>UTF-8</project.build.sourceEncoding>
    <org.richfaces.bom.version>4.3.1.Final</org.richfaces.bom.version>
</properties>
<dependencies>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>javax.faces</groupId>
        <artifactId>javax.faces-api</artifactId>
        <version>${spec.snapshot.version}</version>
        <scope>provided</scope>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>javax</groupId>
        <artifactId>javaee-api</artifactId>
        <version>6.0</version>
        <scope>provided</scope>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.richfaces</groupId>
        <artifactId>richfaces-bom</artifactId>
        <version>${org.richfaces.bom.version}</version>

        <type>pom</type>
    </dependency>    
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.richfaces.ui</groupId>
        <artifactId>richfaces-components-ui</artifactId>
        <version>4.3.1.Final</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.richfaces.core</groupId>
        <artifactId>richfaces-core-impl</artifactId>
        <version>4.3.1.Final</version>
    </dependency>
</dependencies>

<repositories>
    <repository>
        <id>java.net-maven2-SNAPSHOT-repository</id>
        <name>Java.net SNAPSHOT-Repository for Maven</name>
        <url>https://maven.java.net/content/repositories/snapshots/</url>
        <layout>default</layout>
    </repository>
    <repository>
        <id>java.net-maven2-repository</id>
        <name>Java.net Repository for Maven</name>
        <url>https://maven.java.net/content/repositories/releases/</url>
        <layout>default</layout>
    </repository>
</repositories>
</project>
```

Does anyone know what I am doing wrong? (Or how I should set this up in the new project so that it works?)

Richfaces tutorials and answers to similar stackoverflow questions do not help resolving this problem. I have searched the following topics of stackoverflow:

[How to add richfaces to maven project](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14675930/how-to-add-richfaces-to-maven-project)

[java.lang.IllegalStateException: Illegal attempt to set ViewHandler after a response has been rendered](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8831281/java-lang-illegalstateexception-illegal-attempt-to-set-viewhandler-after-a-resp)

[java.lang.IllegalStateException: Illegal attempt to set ViewHandler after a response has been rendered - Jsf1.2 in Weblogic 12c](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22416059/java-lang-illegalstateexception-illegal-attempt-to-set-viewhandler-after-a-resp)