# Upgrad to Wildfly 8.2 with error

Tags: wildfly-8

I upgraded from Wildfly 8.1 to 8.2. My first JSF request resulted in this error, where this worked before.

What is the culprit? Does one need to update any dependencies? JDK 8 required?

```
16:39:36,127 ERROR [io.undertow.request] (default task-1) L:80 UT005023: Exception handling request to /ccms/splitter.xhtml: java.lang.IllegalStateException
    at com.sun.faces.context.FacesContextImpl.assertNotReleased(FacesContextImpl.java:705) [jsf-impl-2.2.8-jbossorg-1.jar:]
    at com.sun.faces.context.FacesContextImpl.getAttributes(FacesContextImpl.java:237) [jsf-impl-2.2.8-jbossorg-1.jar:]
    at org.richfaces.context.ExtendedPartialViewContext.setInstance(ExtendedPartialViewContext.java:55) [richfaces-core-api-4.3.4.Final.jar:4.3.4.Final]
    at org.richfaces.context.ExtendedPartialViewContext.release(ExtendedPartialViewContext.java:64) [richfaces-core-api-4.3.4.Final.jar:4.3.4.Final]
    at org.richfaces.context.ExtendedPartialViewContextImpl.release(ExtendedPartialViewContextImpl.java:424) [richfaces-core-impl-4.3.4.Final.jar:4.3.4.Final]
    at com.sun.faces.context.FacesContextImpl.release(FacesContextImpl.java:591) [jsf-impl-2.2.8-jbossorg-1.jar:]
    at javax.faces.webapp.FacesServlet.service(FacesServlet.java:665) [jboss-jsf-api_2.2_spec-2.2.8.jar:2.2.8]
    at io.undertow.servlet.handlers.ServletHandler.handleRequest(ServletHandler.java:85) [undertow-servlet-1.1.0.Final.jar:1.1.0.Final]
    at io.undertow.servlet.handlers.security.ServletSecurityRoleHandler.handleRequest(ServletSecurityRoleHandler.java:61) [undertow-servlet-1.1.0.Final.jar:1.1.0.Final]
    at io.undertow.servlet.handlers.ServletDispatchingHandler.handleRequest(ServletDispatchingHandler.java:36) [undertow-servlet-1.1.0.Final.jar:1.1.0.Final]
    at org.wildfly.extension.undertow.security.SecurityContextAssociationHandler.handleRequest(SecurityContextAssociationHandler.java:78)
    at io.undertow.server.handlers.PredicateHandler.handleRequest(PredicateHandler.java:43) [undertow-core-1.1.0.Final.jar:1.1.0.Final]
    at io.undertow.servlet.handlers.security.SSLInformationAssociationHandler.handleRequest(SSLInformationAssociationHandler.java:131) [undertow-servlet-1.1.0.Final.jar:1.1.0.Final]
    at io.undertow.servlet.handlers.security.ServletAuthenticationCallHandler.handleRequest(ServletAuthenticationCallHandler.java:56) [undertow-servlet-1.1.0.Final.jar:1.1.0.Final]
    at io.undertow.server.handlers.PredicateHandler.handleRequest(PredicateHandler.java:43) [undertow-core-1.1.0.Final.jar:1.1.0.Final]
    at io.undertow.security.handlers.AuthenticationConstraintHandler.handleRequest(AuthenticationConstraintHandler.java:51) [undertow-core-1.1.0.Final.jar:1.1.0.Final]
    at io.undertow.security.handlers.AbstractConfidentialityHandler.handleRequest(AbstractConfidentialityHandler.java:45) [undertow-core-1.1.0.Final.jar:1.1.0.Final]
    at io.undertow.servlet.handlers.security.ServletConfidentialityConstraintHandler.handleRequest(ServletConfidentialityConstraintHandler.java:63) [undertow-servlet-1.1.0.Final.jar:1.1.0.Final]
    at io.undertow.servlet.handlers.security.ServletSecurityConstraintHandler.handleRequest(ServletSecurityConstraintHandler.java:56) [undertow-servlet-1.1.0.Final.jar:1.1.0.Final]
    at io.undertow.security.handlers.AuthenticationMechanismsHandler.handleRequest(AuthenticationMechanismsHandler.java:58) [undertow-core-1.1.0.Final.jar:1.1.0.Final]
    at io.undertow.servlet.handlers.security.CachedAuthenticatedSessionHandler.handleRequest(CachedAuthenticatedSessionHandler.java:70) [undertow-servlet-1.1.0.Final.jar:1.1.0.Final]
    at io.undertow.security.handlers.SecurityInitialHandler.handleRequest(SecurityInitialHandler.java:76) [undertow-core-1.1.0.Final.jar:1.1.0.Final]
    at io.undertow.server.handlers.PredicateHandler.handleRequest(PredicateHandler.java:43) [undertow-core-1.1.0.Final.jar:1.1.0.Final]
    at org.wildfly.extension.undertow.security.jacc.JACCContextIdHandler.handleRequest(JACCContextIdHandler.java:61)
    at io.undertow.server.handlers.PredicateHandler.handleRequest(PredicateHandler.java:43) [undertow-core-1.1.0.Final.jar:1.1.0.Final]
    at io.undertow.server.handlers.PredicateHandler.handleRequest(PredicateHandler.java:43) [undertow-core-1.1.0.Final.jar:1.1.0.Final]
    at io.undertow.servlet.handlers.ServletInitialHandler.handleFirstRequest(ServletInitialHandler.java:261) [undertow-servlet-1.1.0.Final.jar:1.1.0.Final]
    at io.undertow.servlet.handlers.ServletInitialHandler.dispatchRequest(ServletInitialHandler.java:247) [undertow-servlet-1.1.0.Final.jar:1.1.0.Final]
    at io.undertow.servlet.handlers.ServletInitialHandler.access$000(ServletInitialHandler.java:76) [undertow-servlet-1.1.0.Final.jar:1.1.0.Final]
    at io.undertow.servlet.handlers.ServletInitialHandler$1.handleRequest(ServletInitialHandler.java:166) [undertow-servlet-1.1.0.Final.jar:1.1.0.Final]
    at io.undertow.server.Connectors.executeRootHandler(Connectors.java:197) [undertow-core-1.1.0.Final.jar:1.1.0.Final]
    at io.undertow.server.HttpServerExchange$1.run(HttpServerExchange.java:759) [undertow-core-1.1.0.Final.jar:1.1.0.Final]
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1145) [rt.jar:1.7.0_45]
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:615) [rt.jar:1.7.0_45]
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:744) [rt.jar:1.7.0_45]
```

Any hints highly appreciated.

Comment: We have the same issues after upgrade to WF 8.2. This seems to be a problem with the mojarra implemantation. We are trying to upgrade to mojarra 2.2.9 or downgrade to 2.2.6 (WF 8.1 level)

Answer (score 1):

The problem is jsf-impl jar file (Mojarra project). Downgrade to jsf-impl-2.2.6-jbossorg-4.jar and you will be ok. (I believe 8.2 is using 2.2.8; I tried 2.2.7 and it does not work either...) If you need instructions how to downgrade, let me know.

Comment: I tried downgrading directly through maven, but it didn't work. Could you please provide instructions on how to downgrade?

Answer (score 0):

Even though its been a long time, I'm answering to keep it as a reference, in case anyone looks for it in the near future.
According to [this](https://issues.jboss.org/browse/RF-13685) JSF 2.2.7 is the culprit. Upgrading Wildfly should do the trick now.